# Accelerated C++ header file not working

Tags: c++, dictionary, parameters

I'm trying to compile the second exercise in chapter 7 written in the book. I created a header file containing the xref function:

```
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "split.h"

std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > xref(std::istream&, std::vector<std::string> find_words(const std::string&) = split);
```

Afterwards I wrote the .cpp file:

```
#include "xref.h"
using namespace std;

map<string, vector<int> > xref(istream& in, vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split) {
    ...
}
```

I cannot compile the code, it says parameter 1 does not match. What's wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Are you trying to pass function is parameter #1? Also default argument should be set in declaration only, not in definition.

Comment: In the code shown you don't include any of the stream headers, like `<istream>`.

Comment: I get this: error C2572: 'xref': redefinition of default parameter parameter 1

Comment: @AwesomeGuy: just remove the default parameter from the definition (i.e., the `= split`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says exactly what went wrong: you should specify default parameter value only in function declaration, whereas you did it again in function definition. The error refers to the last parameter of your function.

Comment: No problem. You may accept this answer if you think it's solved your problem.